# Steeltoe3.0 AddCloudFoundryConfiguration throws exception

Tags: cloud-foundry, .net-5, steeltoe

I have upgraded my app to .net 5 and hence upgraded steeltoe also to 3.0, but when i run the app I get an exception as "could not load type 'steeltoe.extensions.configuration.cloudfoundry.service' from assembly 'steeltoe.extensions.configuration.cloudfoundry base", I am using Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundry, I am using serilog too so should I upgrade serilog even, from the past two days I am unable to find the solution for the same.

here is the code snippet

```
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                  .UseEnvironment($"{_environment}")
                  .AddCloudFoundryConfiguration()
                  .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Could not load type` exception can happen if you have mismatched versions of Steeltoe included in your project. Try making sure all Steeltoe packages are on the same version.